# Spark IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, apache-spark

in my code :

```
 def cleanseRDD(autoStr):
        if isinstance(autoStr, int):
            return autoStr
        att3 = autoStr.split(",")[3]
        att5 = autoStr.split(",")[5]

        if att3 == "two":
            att3 = "2"
        else:
            att3 = "4"
        att5 = att5.upper()
        return ",".join(att3)
```

error :

```
  File "D:/Programming/spark/venv/spark.py", line 135, in cleanseRDD
    att3 = autoStr.split(",")[3]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How Can I Pix?

use python ver : 3.7.4

use program : Pycharm

Comment: What have you tried? What do you understand from the error message?

Comment: Can you print autoStr. You will get to know why this error is coming. After splitting against ",". the index referred is greater than the length of list

Comment: you can pix it if you take a look at `autoStr` and check how many values are returned after splitting

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It's because I'm still a beginner...

Comment: @RoadBris Pardon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it `print ('len:', len (autoStr.split(",")))`

Probably less than 3 or 5.

This error occurred by requesting an index larger than the size of the list.

It is recommended to change the following:

```html
def cleanseRDD(autoStr):
        if isinstance(autoStr, int):
            return autoStr
        
        s = autoStr.split(",")

        # Exception
        if len(s) < 5:
            return '<5'
            
        att3 = s[3]
        att5 = s[5]

        ....
```